# Using keypad with curses

Tags: python, curses

I'm using curses for python 3.4, and I need a simple way to count with the arrow keys, every time I press up, x adds 1 to itself, press down, it subtracts one from itself.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this I believe should work?

```
count = 0
while True:
    char = screen.getch()
    if char == 113: exit()  
    elif char == curses.KEY_UP: count+= 1
    ...
    ...
    ..
    .
```

Comment: thats what i thought, but curses doesnt seem to recognize arrow inputs wih getch(), but it fixed when i wrapped it up for some reason...

Comment: The example doesn't do [stdscr.keypad](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.keypad)(yes)